# How can we apply relying on Jesus in situations where it appears we have to rely on ourselves?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, faith

I ask the question for a real reason. I would like to make more money to support my family and live in better conditions. I feel I have to rely on myself to go back to school, work hard and then get a great job. However, I hear something different at Church, rely on Jesus for our needs.

How can we apply relying on Jesus in situations where it appears we have to rely on ourselves?

Do you have specific real life examples of how you do this?

How do you define this and where do you draw the line?

**EDIT**
Marc in his comment below brought up a good topic of: "do what you were going to do anyway" vs (what I interpret as) completely leaning back on Jesus....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me flip the question around a little bit:  Is there anything about going back to school, working hard, and interviewing for (notice I didn't say "getting") a great job that is inherently *not* relying on God?

There's two sides to this coin: Using the talents God has given you, and being faithful to use them for his glory.

God made you a certain way, and make no bones about it, *he is the one who gave you the talents you have.*  So when it comes to relying on God in that sense, you already are.  In fact, it takes God to even allow you to breathe.  Everything you have, and everything you are is from God, so in that sense, you're *always* relying on him.

And there comes a point when we have to realize that working is part of God's will for us.  I am a programmer, but if I sit behind my computer, never write a line of code, and trust Jesus to write it for me, I'll probably get fired, and Paul would say, I'm worse than an infidel for not providing for my family.  Work is still relying on God.  It's the means he's given us that he uses to provide us with the things we need.

Also, in each of our lives, we will each have several opportunities to make bad decisions.  As you go back to school, you have the opportunity to either learn what they're teaching properly, or you'll have the opportunity to cheat on your tests.  Cheat, and you're not relying on God.  Do the best you can, and you are.

You'll also have the opportunity to overwork yourself and neglect your family.  Work so hard that they never see you, and your wife and kids forget who you are, and you're probably not relying on God.  Work as hard as you can without neglecting the roles and responsibilities God has given you, and you probably are.

Ecclesiastes 9:10 says:

> Whatever your hand finds to do, do it with your might, for there is no
>   work or thought or knowledge or wisdom in Sheol, to which you are
>   going.

*Whatever* your hand finds to do.  In whatever roles you find yourself in, do them well.  If you find yourself in the role of father, do that well.  Of husband, do that well.  Of student, do that well.  Of employee, do that well.

Ultimately, it takes wisdom.  Ask Jesus: Should I take on this role of student?  If you feel you can without irreparably damaging your other roles, and you're open and honest about that, then I think you're in a good place.

I wouldn't over-think the whole "relying on God" thing.  He's given you certain characteristics because he wants you to use them to his glory.  Do the best you can, and trust him with the results.

Comment: An interesting answer, but I'm struggling to see in there where the distinction is between "relying on" and "indifference to" - by which I simply mean that it seems the key point here is "do what you were going to do anyway". A supportive answer, though.

Comment: yeah, "do what you were going to do anyway" seems to come to mind and feels contradictory to what I hear in Church.

Comment: I don't think there's a huge distinction.  Paul gives us some instruction in 1 Corinthians 7:17-21, that we should remain in the way we were when we were called, but if a slave can gain freedom, then he should.  Obviously there's tons of freedom here to make decisions using our brains, and make the best life we can, always realizing that it's God's decision in the end whether or not he'll bless us.  There's enough overspiritualization within the church today, that I don't think I need to add to it.  Love God, avoid sin, love others, and do what you're good at.  Read Ecclesiastes for more.

Comment: Oh, and be thankful for Christ's grace and his forgiveness.  Christianity is about a man who died for us, so that we might have our freedom (See the entire book of Galatians for this).  We have to rely on Jesus for our salvation and sanctification.  Beyond that, he's given us tons of freedom to make our decisions ourselves.

Comment: @DavidMorton: went back to read your answer, good info,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In All Things trust In Jesus through his Gospel of Grace, Grace Personified is Jesus. By All means Plan and Work and your talents will show you the way but Pray everyday that you make the right decision and the Holy Spirit Guides you in every step. As he is in Heaven So are we in this world. 1 John 4:17. He is not poor, he is not sick, he does not have lacks,, hence so are we in this world because we died and Rose with him.The Storms for the believer and the Non believer are going to be the same BUT the believers Rock is Solid Foundations. That foundation is Jesus. Next thing is to trust in him completely. Then All the minute questions you have will fade away giving you Peace. The scripture says in John 14: Let not your hearts be troubled" Don't let your heart be troubled but trust in the saviour's love for you.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). This is a strange answer to a strange question.  I'd suggest maybe trying a more answerable question for your first.